# Does every element in exterior algebra have the form $v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge ... \wedge v_k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, exterior-algebra, grassmannian

Does every element in $\wedge ^k V$ can be expressed as the form $v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge ... \wedge v_k$ ? Here $V$ is a n-dim vector space, and $v_i$ are vectors in $V$.

Intuitively it is right, but I have problem in how to make the sum of two forms of $v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge ... \wedge v_k$ still have this form .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As a counterexample, take $V=\Bbb R^4$ with basis $e_1,\dots,e_4$. Note that the vector
$$
e_1 \wedge e_2 + e_3\wedge e_4 \in \wedge^2V
$$
cannot be written in such a fashion.